# What is a reasonable way to secure an asp:fileupload

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, file-upload

I just read this article: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm which discusses some of the security risks involved with allowing users to upload files to your webserver.

I am currently working on an application page which will accept resumes (presumably office, pdf, open office docs, etc) using the asp:FileUpload control. I started with <s>blacklisting certain file</s> only allowing certain file extensions, and now after doing a bit of research I am wondering what are some other methods that are commonly used to increase security.

In my case it is a asp.net 3.5 web application written in C#. Served by IIS7.5 running on Windows Server 2008r2.

Comment: For "security" make sure the server has an SSL cert and your upload page is https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tips would be:

- Make sure the files are uploaded only to directories that are not directly accessible from the web (e.g. use the .NET `App_Data` folder, or a folder outside of the IIS root). An alternative to this is to write your file stream into an `image` database column, or equivalent if not using SQL Server.
- Write a HTTP Handler that can check permissions, roles, etc, which will read the file as a stream and output it to response only if the user is authorised (authentication checks should be done using `web.config` settings).
- Use a system generated file name to protect against unauthorised overwrites.

So many times I've seen uploads implemented that simply write to a folder, and the developer doesn't realise (or care) that the file can then be accessed via http://www.example.com/files/JustUploaded.pdf without authentication and/or authorisation.

Comment: the `image` datatype is deprecated, should be using `varbinary(max)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you can parse them into streams so you won't save the file of the uploader but you save your parsed version.
- Also rename the file and store it in a specific folder (with specific rights) and not on the same disc as your OS (seperate partition)
- Use POST instead of PUT
- Scan for viruses?
- Restrict the maximum size

and most importantly: validate everything

There are probably a lot more things you can check

Comment: Yes it's worth virus scanning IMO if the files will be stored on a file system you control.